# How to show user messages inbox based on conversation query?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii

I'm trying to show user inbox on Yii Application but I can't write a right criteria.

Conversation is based on (user_id, recipient_id) ... so there is no conversation table, and my problem is how to sort list conversations without conversations table ?!

and what about if I used yii relations ?!

**Table structure:**

```
id (int)
message (text)
user_id (int)
recipient_id (int)
sent_at (int)
```

**and my criteria is:**

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition = "recipient_id=:user_id OR user_id=:user_id";
    // $criteria->group ='user_id';
    // $criteria->select ='*';
    // $criteria->distinct = true;
    $criteria->order = "sent_at ASC";
    $criteria->limit = 5;
    $criteria->params = array(':user_id' => Yii::app()->user->id);
    $model = UserMessage::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

**Output**

It's shown all messages recipient

Comment: your condition needs two parameters but you only gave it one. could that be the problem?

Comment: @Tim3880 no because it's user inbox page (messges list) and I have user id only

Answer (score 3):

You have to group by the message itself. However, if this is a large text/string field, this will not be an efficient query on the database, and will be very slow. I will urge you to relook at your database structure.

I have implemented something very similar, but I have converted my table to show the relationship between messages.

```
id (int)
message (text)
user_id (int)
recipient_id (int)
sent_at (int)
reply_to (int) default 0      ;;; I added this field
```

Using this I can search top level conversations

```
SELECT * from user_message where reply_to is NULL or reply_to = 0;
```

Using this scheme, for a **new** message, the reply_to field will be 0.

In Yii

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = "reply_to is NULL or reply_to = 0";
$criteria->order = "sent_at ASC";
$criteria->limit = 5;
$model = UserMessage::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

When viewing a message and creating a reply, set the reply_to code to the value of the upper level. This  allows infinite number of nesting.

```
MSG : I need help with this question (id = 1, reply_to = 0)
MSG : L Re: I need help with this question (id = 2, reply_to = 1)
MSG : L Re: I need help with this question (id = 3, reply_to = 1)
MSG :   L Re: I need help with this question (id = 4, reply_to = 3)
MSG :   L Re: I need help with this question (id = 5, reply_to = 3)
MSG :      L Re: I need help with this question (id = 8, reply_to = 5)
MSG : L Re: I need help with this question (id = 6, reply_to = 1)
MSG :   L Re: I need help with this question (id = 7, reply_to = 6)
```

Comment: nice, I like your table, but I want a list of conversations not messages and your query is shown all messages in conversation

Comment: Actually, using your table structure there is no way to show conversations and there is no mechanism to link messages. If you use the updated query, all new threads will have an empty reply_to code and hence the query will list only the first message on the threads. All other messages in the thread will have a non-empty reply_to and will not be shown.

Comment: ok I was trying, so you think replay_to can do the job.. or what do you think ?.. what if I use conv_id or i'll just use php conditions ?

Comment: I think using the reply_to field will be easier to use. You just need to keep track of the parent (not the conversation) and it allows you to use nested levels of conversation. I cleaned up and updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not added more information in the database table, you can't divide messages into conversations

Unless, your conversations are `user_id - recipient_id` unique.

In that case you can `Group By user_id, recipient_id`

Comment: Yeah, although get used to `group by`, is more powerful

Comment: ok I did it, and it's shown now 2 conversations from about 10.. so how can I make it just one conversations ?!

Comment: What do you want to show: a list of conversations or a list of messages from a conversaton ?

Comment: list of conversations

Comment: Then that it's the answer. You should be getting the right results